# Power for 12V SainSmart relay

Tags: power

I just get my Raspberry Pi and want to start working on a project.

Can anyone offer some insight into what I need to power this [12V SainSmart relay](http://www.sainsmart.com/16-channel-12v-relay-module-for-pic-arm-avr-dsp-arduino-msp430-ttl-logic.html) for my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: https://github.com/fixedd/RPi_SainSmart_Interface#readme